# Is it possible to make a function return a typename in C++?

Tags: c++, function, type-conversion, decltype, typename

My question concerns the possibility of creating a C++ function or similar construct to return a *typename* (as opposed to an object/reference/pointer of some type, as is typical).

As shown in the code below, I have a generic "Image" class which simply contains a pointer to data (void*), size of the data, and a member variable defining how the data is represented.  I need the flexibility to represent 8-bit, 16-bit, ... image types with this same class.

When I want to manipulate image data, I currently have to use a switch/case construct (as shown in the example `CopyImage()`) function to reinterpret_cast the void* data pointer to the appropriate type prior to making the copy.  Unfortunately this same switch/case paradigm keeps getting repeated all over the place as I expand with functions that do things other than CopyImage().  It seems messy and duplicative and limits my ability to add support for more types without replicating additional cases in tons of other functions.

```
enum class datatype_t {
    u8,
    u16
};

class Image {       // can be an image with 8 or 16-bit pixel representation
public:
    void * dataPtr_;
    datatype_t dataType_;
    size_t pixels_;
};

void CopyImage(Image& source, uint16_t * dst_ptr) {     // function to copy image agnostic to data represenation
    switch (source.dataType_) {
    case datatype_t::u8:
        std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(source.dataPtr_), source.pixels_, dst_ptr);
        break;
    case datatype_t::u16:
        std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(source.dataPtr_), source.pixels_, dst_ptr);
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const size_t image_size = 100;

    std::vector<Image> image_library;

    // create Image objects, populate details, push to image library 
    Image source_image8;
    source_image8.dataType_ = datatype_t::u8;
    source_image8.pixels_ = image_size;
    source_image8.dataPtr_ = new uint8_t[image_size];
    image_library.push_back(std::move(source_image8));

    Image source_image16;
    source_image16.dataType_ = datatype_t::u16;
    source_image16.pixels_ = image_size;
    source_image16.dataPtr_ = new uint16_t[image_size];
    image_library.push_back(std::move(source_image16));

    auto destination = new uint16_t[image_size];
    CopyImage(image_library[0], destination);       // copy a 8-bit image into 16-bit destination
    CopyImage(image_library[1], destination);       // copy a 16-bit image into 16-bit destination

    // deletes, etc to follow (not shown for conciseness)

}
```

What I *want* is a function which I can include in the <...> of the `reinterpret_cast`, which when called, returns the typename (i.e. uint8_t, uint16_t, etc).  This function would be a member function of the Image class, refer to the dataType_ variable, and provide a typename - similar to what the switch/case statement is doing explicitly for each possible type - but only have to maintain it in once place since it's a function which would be callable from anywhere I'm trying to do the reinterpret_cast<> operation.

For example, a function called `Image::ReturnType()` which could be used like this:

```
std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<source.ReturnType()>(source.dataPtr_), source.pixels_, dst_ptr);
```

and be defined something like this:

```
typename Image::ReturnType() {
   switch (dataType_) {
   case u8:
      return uint8_t;
   case u16:
      return uint16_t;
   }
}
```

I realize this question is begging for a solution that takes advantage of polymorphism or is related to templating the Image class so that I have separate `Image<uint8_t>` and `Image<uint16_t>` types, but this then precludes me from storing a bunch of Image objects (with different pixel representations) in a single `std::vector<Image>`.

Note: If there is a way to store, in a single `std::vector`, objects with different template type specializations, I'm also open to that solution, but I'm afraid that doesn't exist.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can easily store polymorphic types in `std::vector` as pointers to the base class (or better `std::unique_ptr<Base>`) or if you prefer a `std::variant`.

Comment: ^^^^^ And/or give your `Image` template a common, non-template base class

Comment: How about making `Image` a base class then derive with templated classes and access the `Image`s through methods?

Comment: You can also have your `Image` type use the [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) with a polymorphic pimpl type. This way the polymorphism is hidden from the type's user; the type takes care of that detail itself.

Comment: Are you looking for [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)?

Comment: Polymorphism works with pointers. You need a common non-templated base class for your `Image<...>` . You store (smart) pointers to that in your container.

Comment: Does `typeid` and it's accompanying `std::type_info` (from the `<typeinfo>` header) fulfill your need?

Answer (score 2):

All types must be known at compile time. A type is a compile time abstraction. At runtime, types are more or less existant.

Is your `dataType_` variable is known at compile time? If yes, of course you can have a metafunction returning a type:

```
using TypeMap = std::tuple<uint8_t, uint16_t>;

struct Image {
    // ...

    template<datatype_t datatype_id>
    using ReturnType = std::tuple_element_t<static_cast<std::size_t>(datatype_id), TypeMap>;
};
```

Then you can use the metafunction:

```
// the_type_to_use is uint8_t
using the_type_to_use = Image::ReturnType<datatype_t::u8>;
```

---

On the other hand, if the value is known at runtime only, then you must use a runtime distpatch. Whether it's through a variant or a virtual table.

Answer (score 2):

No.

A function can only return an object or a reference (or void).

What you can do is map a value to a type using a templated type alias, or a member type alias of a class template. Example:

```
template<datatype_t>
struct image_return {};

template<>
image_return<u8> {
    using type = std::uint8_t;
};

template<>
image_return<u16> {
    using type = std::uint16_t;
};
```

---

For your use case however, instead of `void*`, it might be better to use `std::variant<std::uint8_t*, std::uint16_t*>`. Or even better, use a variant of `std::vector`s rather than bare pointers to allocated memory.

Comment: Note that the OP can get the [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) of an object, but can't be used in the way the OP wants it.

Answer (score 2):

Polymorphism works with pointers. You need a common non-templated base class for your `Image<...>` . You store (smart) pointers to that in your container.

```
class ImageBase {
   ...;
};

template <typename DataType> 
class Image: public ImageBase {
  std::vector<DataType> data_;
    ...;
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ImageBase>> image_library;
```